# Having MATLAB to run multiple independent functions which contains infinite while loop

Tags: multithreading, matlab, multitasking

I am currently working with three matlab functions to make them run near simultaneously in single Matlab session(as I known matlab is single-threaded), these three functions are allocated with individual tasks, it might be difficult for me to explain all the detail of each function here, but try to include as much information as possible.

They are CONTROL/CAMERA/DATA_DISPLAY tasks, The approach I am using is creating Timer objects to have all the function callback continuously with different callback period time.

1. CONTROL will sending and receiving data through wifi with udp port, it will check the availability of package, and execute callback constantly
2. CAMERA receiving camera frame continuously through tcp and display it, one timer object T1 for this function to refresh the capture frame
3. DATA_DISPLAY display all the received data, this will refresh continuously, so another timer T2 for this function to refresh the display

However I noticed that the timer T2 is blocking the timer T1 when it is executed, and slowing down the whole process. I am working on a system using a multi-core CPU and I would expect MATLAB to be able to execute both timer objects in parallel taking advantage of the computational cores.

Through searching the parallel computing toolbox in matlab, it seems not able to deal with infinite loop or continuous callback, since the code will not finish and display nothing when execute, probably I am not so sure how to utilize this toolbox

Or can anyone provide any good idea of re-structuring the code into more efficient structure.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I see a problem using the parallel computing toolbox here. The design implies that the jobs are controlled via your primary matlab instance. Besides this, the primary instance is the only one with a gui, which would require to let your DISPLAY_DATA-Task control everything. I don't know if this is possible, but it would result in a very strange architecture. Besides this, inter process communication is not the best idea when processing large data amounts.

To solve the issue, I would use Java to display your data and realise the 'DISPLAY_DATA'-Part. The connection to java is very fast and simple to use. You will have to write a small java gui which has a `appendframe`-function that allows your `CAMERA`-Job to push new data. Obviously updating the gui should be done parallel without blocking.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply, because I never come across of using JAVA to interface with Matlab before, did you mean this? [Java Interface](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/product-overview.html), and while CONTROL is running on matlab, it also pass the data information to JAVA, but how about the CAMERA image, will it also running on matlab, and passing the image to JAVA for display as well?